# 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am getting this error while using action mailer to send mail via my gmail account.

> Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in SweepstakesController#show
>   535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.
>    Learn more at:
>          ParticipantMailer.winner_confirmation(@result).deliver_now!

I have double checked my email and password,i have restarted my server,also i have gone through all previous questions related to this error here and implemented every answer but to no avail.
My development.rb file is:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port:        3000}
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method= :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address =>"smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :domain => "gmail.com",
  :user_name => "my_email@gmail.com",
  :password => "my_password",
  :authentication => 'plain',
  :openssl_verify_mode => 'none' 
}
```

Logic in controller:

```
def show
  @sweepstake = Sweepstake.find(params[:id])
  @participant = Participant.where(:sweepstake_id => @sweepstake.id )
  b = @sweepstake.winner_count
  @result = Array.new 
  b.times do 
    @result << @participant[rand(@participant.count)]
  end
  ParticipantMailer.winner_confirmation(@result).deliver_now!
end
```

participant_mailer.rb file:

```
class ParticipantMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'rajesh010794@gmail.com'

  def winner_confirmation(result)
    @result = result
    @url  = 'http://example.com/login'

    Rails.logger.info(@result.inspect)
    @result.each do |i|
      mail(to: i.participant_email, subject: 'Congratulation')
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer Goto `config/initializers/setup_mail.rb` Check whether the configuration there matches the configuration written in the development.rb file.It should look like the following in both files:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
     :address =>"smtp.gmail.com",
     :port => 587,
     :domain => "gmail.com",
     :user_name => "my_mail@gmail.com",
     :password => "**********",
     :authentication => 'plain',
     :enable_starttls_auto => true,
     :openssl_verify_mode => 'none' 
     }
```

This had solved my problem.

Comment: I'm sure you don't need this initializer. Probably Google already propagated changes in your account. If you delete it, just `development.rb` config should be sufficient.

Comment: If you are fixing issue for already existing project then please look for config/initializers/setup_mail.rb settings ...it worked for me too

Answer (score 1):

According to [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail), gmail configuration looks like this:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'example.com',
  user_name:            '<username>',
  password:             '<password>',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

There is `enable_starttls_auto` you are missing. And I think in `domain` you should put your domain, not `gmail.com`.

It worked for me with the settings above after I turned on [less secure applications](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) for my account.

Also as I've read in Google documentation you may need to use [Unlock Captcha](https://accounts.google.com/displayunlockcaptcha).

Comment: i have tried with enable_starttls_auto also, but one of the answer suggested to try removing it, and gmail.com is my email domain

Comment: i am using Rails 4.2.1

Comment: i have tried that also sir,but i could not resolve the issue

Comment: @Supertracer I turned it ON several times :) before it worked. Something strange happening. When I exit this page and return back, it will be turned-off. After several such attempts, it's finally ON.

Comment: Try to exit this page and return back. Is the flag still ON?

Comment: it is on , i tried refreshing and exiting the page it remains on everytime

Comment: sir,can sending multiple emails could be the problem? in the result array i have multiple participants records.

Comment: @Supertracer please try "Unlock Captcha" (link in my answer) and limit receivers list to one (I'm sure it's not a problem, but for sure). Also allow it several minutes before testing again. I think it takes time for Google to propagate changes to all apps.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent hours battling this problem and reconfiguring my `Gmail` and `Rails` setting for `two-factor authorization`, etc. and in the end, the real problem was that I had this file lurking in my app -- 
`config/initializers/setup_mail.rb`  -- from years ago and it had the old settings. Once I removed this file, all the other advice on Stack for solving this problem worked.